# firebase-queue, there is a delay in the rate at which the worker receives task

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-queue

I push 100 tasks to the queue on the client side like this.

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('queue/tasks');
for(var i = 0;i<100;i++){
 ref.push({'foo': 'bar',i:i})
};
```

At the server, my worker looks like this

```
var queue = new Queue(ref, function(data, progress, resolve, reject){
  console.log(data);
  resolve();
}
```

The issue is that to complete processing all the tasks, it takes about **60 seconds**, which is way to slow. Is there any way my worker can receive the tasks faster. I want to use the queue for the my client to send a request to the server. But with the current speed of the queue, I will not be able to support many concurrent users. I am looking to support 50k concurrent users.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I noticed is that you don't have any options being passed in, and you can set a number of workers that will pull simultaneously from your Queue.

```
options = {
  'numWorkers': 5,
  'sanitize': false,
  'suppressStack': true,
}    
var queue = new Queue(ref, options, function(data, progress, resolve, reject){
  console.log(data);
  resolve();
})
```

However, while I did notice a speed increase on my machine, with 1 worker my process ran through 100 in about 9 seconds, but with 5 concurrent workers it finished in about 5 seconds.

I'm on a brand new 13" MacBookPro with the i7 chip.

I used performance-now to perform my benchmarks by doing this before the Queue is set up:

```
var start = now();
```

and this after the *resolve()* inside the Queue

```
console.log(((now()-start)/1000).toFixed(3));
```

Comment: 9 seconds for 100 tasks is still very high when compared to the request directly served by the node server. The limitation here I don't think is the worker/server machine, as the rate at which it receives the request is itself very slow.

Comment: I agree that it is still slow, and at that type of scale, I'm sure you need to consider other solutions for your message queue.